# are nodejs https 3rd party api requests encrypted?

Tags: node.js, https

I'm sorry if this is a daft question.

I'm developing an application that uses oauth2 to integrate with a 3rd party api via a server-side flow in node.

The one thing I'd like to confirm is that when I make the final post request to the 3rd party api to retrieve the access token using the node https module is whether or not the connection is encrypted.

From what I gather, when an https request is made from a browser, the browser handles encrypting the data on the client side. Does node encrypt the data in a similar way, or is this something that I need to implement myself?

If there is some background info that I've somehow overlooked in this regard, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: if the OAuth API service you're querying is served over HTTPS, then your HTTP library (most likely [request](https://github.com/request/request)) is already handling encryption transparently for you. Any time you make a request to an HTTPS endpoint, your request WILL FAIL if the client is not handling encryption properly.

Comment: That's great, thanks for straightforward answer. I'm always suspicious when things seem to 'just work' :)